# Are Community Promotion Ads shown based on keywords in questions?

Tags: discussion

I came across this while I was browsing through the Newest Questions.
Are Community Promotion Ads shown based on keywords in questions?
Or was this just a happy coincidence?

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as far as I can tell. I did few searches then checked the top question to see if I could find a pattern.

- "virtualisation" did not produce *VirtualBox* ads on the top 2 questions (I got the *7zip* ad and *synergy*),
- "zip file" or "7 zip" did not produce the *7zip* ad (I got *xperf*),
- when I searched for "xperf" the top three questions didn't give me a community promotion ad (?)
- and as a final test I did "VLC" and picked the top one, which gave me an ad for *English.SE*.

So no – they do not seem any way tied to searches or the question you are viewing.